# Why am I getting "undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby

isn't `+` an operator?  why would it not be defined?

here's my code:

```
Class Song
  @@plays = 0
  def initialize(name, artist, duration)
    @name = name
    @artist = artist
    @duration = duration
    @plays = 0
  end
  attr_reader :name, :artist, :duration,
  attr_writer :name, :aritist, :duration
  def play
    @plays += 1
    @@plays += 1
    "This Song:  #@plays play(s).  Total #@@plays plays."
  end
  def to_s
    "Song: #@name--#@artist (#@duration)"
  end
end
```

Comment: Not related, but I'd recommend against a class and instance variable with the same name; rather name the class variable `@@total_plays` or something like that. Just too easy to make a mistake otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

First, this code doesn't even run: `class` on Line 1 needs to be spelled with a lowercase c, and you can't have a comma after the last item in a statement (your `attr_reader` line).  I don't get a `NoMethodError` after fixing those and running `Song.new` or `Song#play` or `Song#to_s`.

Anyway, you will always get that `NoMethodError` when you try adding *anything* to a `nil` value:

```
>> nil + 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):1
>> nil + nil
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
>> # @foo is not defined, so it will default to nil
?> @foo + 2
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
```

So you might be trying to add something to an uninitialized instance variable... or it could be anything.  You always need to post full, minimal code to duplicate an error if you want to be helped properly.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is defined on numbers (among other things). However, as the error message says, it is not defined on `nil`. This means you can't do `nil + something` and why would you?

That being said, you're actually not calling `nil + something` anywhere in the code you've shown (you're initializing both `@plays` and `@@plays` to 0, and you're not setting them to `nil` at any point). And as a matter of fact your code runs just fine once you remove the two syntax error (`Class` should be `class` and there should be no comma after `:duration`). So the error is not in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should include `@@plays = 0` in your initialize method?

Comment: Why? It's a class variable initialized to 0 on declaration.